# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

When trying to authenticate users with Mongoose I get the following warning in my console:

`(node:20114) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:20114) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20114) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Trying to trace the stack doesn't result in anything, all I get is `undefined`. Similar questions exist here on Stackoverflow, but they don't apply to my situation. Any idea what this could cause?

My route controller is calling the `findByCredentials` function inside the Mongoose model:

**Controller**

```
static login(req, res) {
    User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
      .then(user => {
        return user.generateAuthToken().then(token => {
          res.header("x-auth", token).json(user);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials." });
      });
  }
```

**Model**

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
  return this.findOne({ email }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      Promise.reject();
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
        res ? resolve(user) : reject();
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: can you post your `generateAuthToken()` method?

Comment: `Promise.reject();` aren't you missing a return statement there? Based on the logic in that callback it would seem that was what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `undefined` is coming from your `Promise.reject()` you are not passing any error message to it, so you are literally throwing undefined.

It is not caught in the catch in login, because you are not returning it from your `findByCredentials` method.

**Solution:**

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
    return this.findOne({ email }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            return Promise.reject('User not available');
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
                res ? resolve(user) : reject();
            });
        });
    });
};
```